# insert image with tinyMCE in asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I'm using tinyMVC as an Editor in my MVC project, Now I can copy and past mixture of text and image in it and it works well , as I want it !
but my concern is that after uploading my project it wont work and wont display images !
has anybody experience about that? should I upload image separately and rather than text ?? or it is OK and will work fine ??
please help me about that , thanks

Comment: do you save the editor content anywhere?

Comment: what do you mean ? I have a post table and a body(nvarchar(MAX)) field ,and present it in UI via displaytextfor() in MVC, my questions is this , I should save the images in post separately or in that field ??

Comment: i do not have an anser in this case, mvc is beyond my horizon

Comment: it is not about MVC, I just wanted to tell you more details ,is it possible to save a post with text and image in nvarchar(MAX) field with tinyMCE or I should save each of image in another table ??

Comment: what about base64-encoding your images. i gues they aren't displayed later on because the link is not working